# JPA EntitiyManager - find Parent by id does not return instance with previously added children

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, orm, jpa-2.0

Suppose we have standard one-to-many relationship between Parent and Child objects. In other words, one Parent holds list of Child objects.

Mapping is standard... Ids in both classes are annotated with @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)... There are all getters and setters...

```
Parent{
    ....
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent")
    Collection<Child> children;
    ....
}

Child{
    ...
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    Parent parent;
    ...
}
```

Child object is the owning side of relation. When I save owning Child object, and after that fetch Parent object, I expect to get previously saved Child within parent. More precise, when I execute this code:

```
EntityManager em... 
Parent p = new Parent();
em.persist(p);
em.flush();

Child c = new Child();
c.setParent(p);
em.persist(c);
em.flush();

Parent savedParent = em.find(Parent.class, p.getId());
savedParent.getChildren().size(); //this call returns 0 instead of 1 (why?)
```

...I expect that savedParent has in collection previously saved one child. But, for some reason, this does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default @OneToMany has set fetch = FetchType.LAZY, set it as FetchType.EAGER.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

UPDATE

```
savedParent.getChildren().size(); //this call returns 0 instead of 1 (why?)
```

With *em.find(Parent.class, p.getId());* you are getting the entity from the First Level Cache. The Parent entity has been cached(without children) and saved in the database that's why you get 0 children. All you need to do is clean the session before calling the Parent. This will make a call to the database with your parent then  *savedParent.getChildren().size()* must work.

```
EntityManager em... 
Parent p = new Parent();
em.persist(p);
em.flush();

Child c = new Child();
c.setParent(p);
em.persist(c);
em.flush();

em.clear(); //this will clear first level cache

Parent savedParent = em.find(Parent.class, p.getId()); // a sql is peformed
savedParent.getChildren().size(); //a sql is peformed for children.
```

PD: Be aware with the clear method, if you havent flushed yet do not call it.

Comment: Thank you very much on response. I updated my question. Maybe I'm in wrong, but lazy loading is performed when, for example, i call size method on children collection... But, that call in my scenario returns value 0. Again, is there something wrong with my understanding how bidirectional one-to-many relation between entities works and how it can be established.

Comment: Thanks again! Of course, but there is nothing about some error or similar  in logs . It is very strange behavior. As far as I know, my above assumption and logic is theoretically correct and ti will be OK for me just to get confirmation about my expectations from code mentioned in question... If my expectations are correct, then I will take some deeper research on this issue... I have some pressure at the time, so any info that reduces number of possible mistakes means a lot.

Comment: You got the point. It's been a while since I worked with JPA/Hibernate... I think that i missed semantic of flush operation... It synchronizes persistence context TO the database, but not database TO persistence context. For later, I suppose that the most appropriate operation is refresh in EntityManager, probably better then clear cache. Do you agree?